# How can I import react into my background.js chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, import

I have react code that I wanted included into my background.js but I get the following error: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Import that is causing the error:

`import React, { useState } from 'react'`

I've done some research and tried adding  `type: module` but that does not work.

What can I do to solve this

Comment: Background scripts don't have a view layer, why would you want to import react in the first place?

Comment: I have a counter timer where I used a react library that I want to continue counting down when user tabs out the extension pop up.

Comment: The timer works fine when popup is open, but I need it to continue counting down even when user tabs out of pop up. I'm using ```react-countdown```

Comment: React is just a view library. You need to keep track of the counting logic separately. Importing react in a headless environment wont change that.

Comment: In your opinion what would be the best to do,  create code in background to keep count of the react timer or to just recreate a timer in vanilla js in background.js.

Comment: What do you mean by view layer?

Comment: View layer is an MVC term. (A quick google search gave me this article of MVC in regards to React, https://sudonull.com/post/79895-Honest-MVC-on-React-Redux-Developer-Soft-Blog )

Comment: In my opinion the best thing to do would be to store a time stamp of when the countdown started, then each second you re-render the view and calculate how much time has passed since the original timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

*Based on comments*

**Q:** In your opinion what would be the best to do, create code in background to keep count of the react timer or to just recreate a timer in vanilla js in background.js.

**A:** In my opinion the best thing to do would be to store a timestamp of when the countdown started, then each second you re-render the view and calculate how much time has passed since the original timestamp.

```js
if (!localStorage.getItem('startTime')) {
   localStorage.setItem('startTime', Date.now());
}
const startTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('startTime'), 10);

const writeTime = () => {
  const currentTime = Date.now();
  const secondsDiff = Math.floor((currentTime - startTime) / 1000);
  document.body.innerText = secondsDiff;
};

setInterval(writeTime, 1000);
writeTime();
```

Localstorage isn't available in SO snippets, but they are on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ym9w2hr/20/

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this ASAP. So if user sets time, for example, 5 mins then user tabs away from popup, then comes back a minute later, this coe  will calculate the time that has passed and now show 4 minutes left on the timer? Can background get the time that user has typed it and calculate it?